# Переход на цифру. Нужно ли цифру кавычить?

Tags: кавычки

«Переход на цифру». Нужно ли цифру кавычить? Имеется в виду цифровое ТВ.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не надо кавычек. Это же просторечное сокращение, ещё не зафиксированное словарями.

Как таксомотор - такси, метрополитен - метро.